# SQL Server Backup to a Remote Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realise there is a command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DB Name] TO DISK [PATH]
```

Is it possible to backup to a remote location? - E.G. the web server rather than the database server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Exactly the same syntax as the normal backup command, but replace the path as appropriate, eg:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DB NAME] TO DISK [\\server\share\path]
```

There's an example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179313.aspx that shows this.

You will need to make sure that the SQL server account is able to write files to the named path.

Comment: Perfect, but I would need to have a file with specific permissions on my Web Server that the general public would be able to write-to?

Answer (score 2):

i created a remote full/transact backup template which you can try it out, it checks the local disk space and remote disk space before transfering.

```
git clone https://github.com/jnre/SQL_backupremote.git
```